# Qthread is still working when i close gui on python pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

my code has thread, but when i close the gui, it still works on background. how can i stop threads? is there something stop(), close()?
i dont use signal, slots? Must i use this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import time
import threading

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.kac_ders=QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.bilgi_cek=QtGui.QPushButton("Save")
        self.text=QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.widgetlayout=QtGui.QFormLayout()
        self.widgetlar=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.widgetlar.setLayout(self.widgetlayout)
        self.bilgiler=QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        self.bilgi_cek.clicked.connect(self.on_testLoop)
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widgetlar)
        self.analayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.analayout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.analayout.addWidget(self.bilgi_cek)
        self.analayout.addWidget(self.bilgiler)
        self.centralWidget=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.analayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def on_testLoop(self):
        self.c_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.kontenjan_ara)
        self.c_thread.start()

    def kontenjan_ara(self):

        while(1):
                self.bilgiler.append(self.text.text())
                time.sleep(10)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWidget = Main()
myWidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: This code is not thread safe. You are not allowed to access GUI objects (like `self.text`) from a secondary thread. You should aim to refactor your code to use a `QThread` and signals and slots or simply use one thread and a `QTimer` (since most of the time your thread is sleeping)

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

1. You shouldn't be calling GUI code from outside the main thread.  GUI elements are not thread-safe. `self.kontenjan_ara` updates and reads from GUI elements, it shouldn't be the target of your `thread`.
2. In almost all cases, you should use `QThreads` instead of python threads. They integrate nicely with the event and signal system in Qt.

If you just want to run something every few seconds, you can use a `QTimer`

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    ...
    self.timer = QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.kontenjan_ara)
    self.timer.start(10000)

def kontenjan_ara(self):
    self.bilgiler.append(self.text.text())
```

If your thread operations are more computationally complex you can create a worker thread and pass data between the worker thread and the main GUI thread using signals.

```
class Worker(QObject):

    work_finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def do_work(self):
        data = 'Text'
        while True:
            # Do something with data and pass back to main thread
            data = data + 'text'
            self.work_finished.emit(data)
            time.sleep(10)


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, ...)
        ...
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.worker.work_finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.do_work)
        self.thread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def on_finished(self, data):
        self.bilgiler.append(data)
        ...
```

Qt will automatically kill all the subthreads when the main thread exits the event loop.

Comment: This is much better and more correct than my answer, but I think OP wanted to start a worker on each button click, and wants that worker to read from the GUI, not only notify it asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

I chose to rewrite a bit this answer, because I had failed to properly look at the problem's context. As the other answers and comments tell, you code lacks thread-safety.

The best way to fix this is to try to really think "in threads", to restrict yourself to only use objects living in the same thread, or functions that are known as "threadsafe".

Throwing in some signals and slots will help, but maybe you want to think back a bit to your original problem. In your current code, each time a button is pressed, **a new thread in launched**, that will, every 10 seconds, do 2 things :
 - Read some text from `self.text`
 - Append it to `self.bilgiler`

Both of these operations are non-threadsafe, and **must** be called from the thread that owns these objects (the main thread). You want to make the worker threads "schedule & wait" the read & append oeprations, instead of simply "executing" them.

I recommend using the other answer (the thread halting problem is automatically fixed by using proper QThreads that integrate well with Qt's event loop), which would make you use a cleaner approach, more integrated with Qt.

You may also want to rethink your problem, because maybe there is a simpler approach to your problem, for example : not spawning threads each time `bilgi_cek` is clicked, or using `Queue` objects so that your worker is completely agnostic of your GUI, and only interact with it using threadsafe objects.

Good luck, sorry if I caused any confusion. My original answer is still available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39605384/2). I think it would be wise to mark the other answer as the valid answer for this question.

Comment: thank you, it worked, but i have some questions. when i close the gui, how self.closed is set ?  `self.closed = threading.Event()` does that line understand when i close the gui. it must be signal, isnt it?

Comment: This is handled by overriding `closeEvent`, and calling `self.closed.set()`. Please note that the other answer may be a better solution to your problem, because it directly uses Qt features to make the thread die when the loop stops, and because it also fixes the lack of thread-safety in your code.

Comment: actually i really dont have experience and abilities about pyqt, your solution solved my problem but now, some new problems occured, my code is not simple like that example and there are two threads in my code. Now, i dont even know how can i call variable than other class etc. Other solution's first part worked, but i couldnt understand second part. how i sync with my code, i just think about it. and i am really appreciate for your care, thank you very much again and again.